# Connecting to a database server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, connection, database-server

There is a database server at IP address `192.168.1.11`. There are several databases on that   server. It has authentication, like `user : System` and `pass : 123123` .

Now I want to connect to this server only, not any particular database, and then get a list of databases available on that server.

I know the normal procedure of connecting to a database with `SqlConnection`. But I'm wondering how I could just get connected to the server and get the list of the databases on that server.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008-

Comment: do you need to do this in code? in c#?  Your question is, how do i list all the databases that I have access to on a MSSQL2008 server using C#?

Comment: actually, i have to first select a server name(as i am working in a network). after i select a server name, databases in that server should be listed.

Comment: You cannot connect *just to the server* - you are **always** connecting to a database on that server. You could however connect to that server and the `master` database and then run the query that Obama has suggested

Comment: ok. I got my answare. Thanks for the information @marc_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run this query on a Method

```
SELECT [name] 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE dbid > 4
```

or by

```
String connString ="Data Source=localhost;User ID=username;Password=passwrd;";

        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            DataTable tblDatabases = sqlConn.GetSchema("Databases");
            sqlConn.Close();
            DataTable td = tblDatabases.Select("dbid>6").CopyToDataTable();
         }
```

Comment: 1 question. I am not understanding why we are using dbid>4? is it constant? is it like that, 4 databases are common in a server?

Comment: System databases are under <4 so we set >4 to not include system databases on your list :)